# collection_select doesn't let ActiveRecord update its collection when none of options is selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, collections

I have has_and_belongs_to_many association between two models.

I made use of collection_select to represent the other model in this association in a form. When I tried to deselect options in collection_select, collection_select doesn't post its empty value and, thus, it doesn't let ActiveRecord pass any update clause to the database.

e.g. Parameters are like;
When onptions selected;
  Parameters: {"name_of_model"=>{"name"=>"de2", "other_model_ids"=>["1", "3"]}

When none selected;
  Parameters: {"name_of_model"=>{"name"=>"de2" }

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `other_model_ids` parameter to be an empty array if it is not passed to the controller action:

```
params[:name_of_model][:other_model_ids] ||= []
```

This will ensure that if there is no selection then the model will be updated correctly so that it has no associated model IDs.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I tried to figure out this problem by tweaking erb file and didn't come up with this idea. Thanks a lot